# SQL Server 2008 hosting (for development)

Tags: sql-server-2008, hosting

We are doing distributed development, working at home, office and sometimes at customers.

We are using assembla for source-repository and we need a centralized-remote SQL Server 2008 database hosting for (similar to svn on assembla) our SQL development server.

Can you name / recommend any service providers?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ReliableSite.Net](http://www.reliablesite.net/v3/shared.asp). Get a shared hosting plan with a SQL Server 2008 addon. They allow remote access so you'll be able to develop against it. You'll end up spending under $10/mo for a database up to 1 gb in size.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [DiscountASP](http://www.discountasp.com/) in the past.  I had good luck with them and I've heard others have had good luck with them.

I also recommend source control for your SQL server as well.  Red Gate has an awesome tool ([SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_source_control/index.htm)) that works with my SVN repository.  Great for distributed groups.

Answer (score 0):

You don't centralize the database, you add the database source to source control just like any other source. Developers work on their individual SQL Server Developer Edition instances, properly licensed for each individual developer on its workstation. If possible, developer may use the Express Edition on their workstation.

Your project does not contain any database binary file (.MDF, .NDF, .LDF), it only contains .SQL source files that, when run, they deploy the current version of the application schema. Developers *never* operate on the database with DBA tools, they always operate **all** changes as .SQL scripts added to the source, modifying the deployment procedure accordingly with the schema changes, and providing for appropriate deployment upgrade. See [Version Control and your Database](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/).

Comment: That may or may not work I have a test db of 200gb real data. I have distributing changes here.

Comment: @TomTom: I'm pretty sure those 200Gb are data, not metadata (tables, views, procedures definitions). I'm advocating the scripting of the objects, not the data in those objects (except for data that *is* metadata). 200Gb of test data can be either generated, it can be bcp-ed in after db generation, or it can even represent the *starting* v0 of the db.